# There is nonzero primitive element in finite dimensional pointed hopf algebra over C???

Tags: hopf-algebras

I'm huge confused!

There is nonzero primitive element in finite dimensional pointed hopf algebra over complex field???

I find in several articles,it is said that a is primitive,so a=0.

I will appreciate if someone can give me some clue.

Comment: If $x$ is a primitive element in a Hopf algebra over a field of characteristic $0$, then $1$, $x$, $x^2$, ... are linearly independent over the field (unless $x=0$), so the Hopf algebra cannot be finitely-dimensional.

Comment: (Tell me if you want the proof.)

Comment: Usually, most questions are happy enough with *one* question mark.